# Time Complexity of a loop with decreasing increments

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am a bit confused about the time complexity of the following piece of code (limits are hard-coded to quote example):

```
loss = 3;
for(i=0;i<=10;)
{
    i += loss;
    loss = loss - 0.3; //loss keeps decreasing by some fixed value
}
```

Here, though the variable `i` is constinously increasing approaching to terminate loop, but the rate it increases is itself variable.

Comment: If you replace "10" with a large number, the loop will never terminate since at some point `loss` will become negative.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example the time complexity is `O(1)` because, since it has no arguments, it will always take the same time to execute.

If that number `10` in your for loop was an argument `n` it would be `O(n)` for a small `n`, if the `n` is big enough "loss" would eventually become negative and the program would run forever. The "loss" impacts the time complexity by a constant amount.

Comment: It wouldn't be O(n) -- for large n the code as written would not terminate.

Comment: @Paul Absolutly right, "loss" would eventually be negative and it would run forever